# Chicago citation of quote in quote

Tags: citations, citation-style, quotation

In my paper, I am quoting a sentence which involves a quote from another paper.  I am using Chicago style notes and bibliography. How should I do this? See the example below:

> Hoffman concludes, “Actual class affiliation is not as important for
> the rise of Islamic fundamentalism as ‘an incongruity between high
> aspirations and the decrease in economic and political
> opportunities.’”

Is it enough if I just reference Hoffman like this in my note:

> Valerie J. Hoffman, “Muslim Fundamentalists: Psychosocial Profiles,”
> in Fundamentalisms Comprehended, ed. Martin E. Marty and R. Scott
> Appleby (Chicago: The University of Chicago Press, 1995), 203.

Or should I also in some way include a reference to the reference she uses?

Answer (score 2):

The important issue is not the citation style. The important issue is that you should look at the original source, the paper that Hoffman quotes from. This way you will be able to give credit to the person who wrote it, and it makes sure that you are quoting them accurately.

If that one sentence is all you are quoting from Hoffman, I don't think you should cite her paper at all. Just cite the one she is quoting from.

You might find this paper interesting, about the importance of checking references properly: "Monuments to Academic Carelessness: The Self-fulfilling Prophecy of Katherine Frost Bruner", by Rekdal. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0162243914532138

Comment: Yes, paraphrasing (after looking up the sources) would obviate the need for a "nested citation" as well.

Comment: There are different opinions about this, but I generally want to credit where I *found* the source I'm checking.

Comment: @user2619203 You can cite the publication that cited the earlier one if you want. But if a quotation from someone else is all you are crediting them for, I think it is unnecessary. Checking and citing the original source is the important thing.

Comment: The reason I am not directly including the secondary source is because I am doing a literature review and that paper does not fulfill my inclusion criteria. Paraphrasing Hoffman would definitely solve the problem, but I'm still curious to know whether there are any guidelines how to solve this. For example in a case in which one has a much longer quote

Comment: @arina That isn't a good reason not to include the original source. If you have a list of papers that fulfil your inclusion criteria, then that is OK, and you can put that list in a table to show it clearly. But you should still check and cite the original source.

Comment: @henning I think paraphrasing would be weird. How are you going to express it? I think you would need to mention that she used a direct quote from someone else, and if you do that then you should clearly cite the other person.

Answer (score 1):

Look at 14.273 of the *Chicago Manual of Style* (16th ed.). You can see an example of how it would be formatted here: https://libguides.westsoundacademy.org/c.php?g=457482&p=3156527

Comment: Welcome to Academia! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The linked example doesn't answer the question whether the in-text reference to the source of the "inner" quotation has to be included within the "outer" quotation and if so, how.

Comment: Yes, it does, as does the CMS. See: "Astrik L. Gabriel, "The Educational Ideas of Christine de Pisan," Journal of the History of Ideas 16, no. 1 (1995): 3-21, quoted in Sarah Gwyneth Ross, The Birth of Feminism: Women as Intellect in Renaissance Italy and England (Cambridge: Harvard University Press, 2009), 23." The question did not give the bibliographic information for what Hoffman quoted, but it can be found in the source and formatted per above.

Comment: @user2619203 The CMS only discusses the case in which one wants to quote the part that Hoffman quoted. It says nothing about what you should do when you also include part of the text written by Hoffman.

Comment: In the example in my comment above, Ross = Hoffman, no?

Comment: If you mean that the source you cite first is Hoffman, then I'd add Hoffman's bibliographic information and then "Hoffman cites [bibliographic information of quote]."

Comment: @user2619203 In this case, Hoffman cites Salem, so indeed Ross = Hoffman. However, I do not only cite Salem but also part of what Hoffman wrote.

Comment: In that case, I think my comment immediately above provides a reasonable answer. A more general issue to think about is that, if the CMS does not explicitly provide a model for what you want to do, then no professor or editor is going to have a problem with how you format it, as long as you follow the general guidelines.